# Is there any way to summarize data by reformatting?

Tags: python, r

I am trying to convert data from following Table into another summarized data.

| Sample | Position | Reference | Alternate | No. of Reads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P6 | 10017884 | C | G | 2 |
| P7 | 10017884 | C | G | 1 |
| P8 | 10017884 | C | A | 7 |
| P98 | 10017884 | C | T,A | 4 |
| P114 | 10020433 | A | C | 1 |
| P98 | 10020433 | A | C | 4 |

I am looking for output like following table. In some of the samples, there are data which are missing/empty, so it should be filled with 0 (zero). Any type of hint to solve this problem will be helpful in Linux/R or Python.

| Position | Reference | Aletrnate | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | P7 | P8 | P98 | P114 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10017884 | C | G | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  |  | A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
|  |  | T,A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 10020433 | A | C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using R `tidyr::pivot_wider`, assuming data in dataframe `df1`:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Sample", 
              values_from = "No. of Reads", 
              values_fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  Position Reference Alternate    P6    P7    P8   P98  P114
     <int> <chr>     <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 10017884 C         G             2     1     0     0     0
2 10017884 C         A             0     0     7     0     0
3 10017884 C         T,A           0     0     0     4     0
4 10020433 A         C             0     0     0     4     1
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Sample    Position    Reference   Alternate   'No. of Reads'
P6  10017884    C   G   2
P7  10017884    C   G   1
P8  10017884    C   A   7
P98 10017884    C   T,A 4
P114    10020433    A   C   1
P98 10020433    A   C   4", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.pivot(['Position', 'Reference', 'Alternate'], 'Sample', 'No. of Reads').fillna(0)
```